# Bootstrap datepicker icon

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

My html code is:

```
 <div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy" data-date-viewmode="years" class="form-control date-picker">
  <span class="input-group-addon"> <i class="icon-calendar"></i> </span>
 </div>
```

JS:

$('.date-picker').datepicker();

When I click on icon datepicker is not showing. It shows when I click on input field.

How to make datepicker visible when I click on icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this working code example below and tell me if this works

```
<div class="input-append date" id="datepicker" data-date="dateValue: Customer.DateOfBirth" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy">
<input class="span2" size="16" type="text" data-bind="value: Customer.DateOfBirth" readonly="readonly">
<span class="add-on"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></span>
```

Answer (score 3):

The best way out here would be to add a class, lets say "date" to the containing div, and add the datepicker functionality on that div, like:

```
<div class="input-group date">
  <input type="text" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy" data-date-viewmode="years" class="form-control date-picker">
  <span class="input-group-addon"> <i class="icon-calendar"></i> </span>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.date').datepicker();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your input field has the class `date-picker` whereas your icon does not.

Adding that class might give you the desired behavior, though if you have styling specific to that class, it may affect your icon as well.